# Evaluation of $\int_{[0,\infty)}\biggl(\int_{[0,\infty)}2x\sqrt{y}e^{-x^2\sqrt{y}-y}dy\biggl)dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

> Find the value of 
>   $$\int_{[0,\infty)}\biggl(\int_{[0,\infty)}2x\sqrt{y}e^{-x^2\sqrt{y}-y}dy\biggl)dx$$

My attept:

Let $f(x,y)=2x\sqrt{y}e^{-x^2\sqrt{y}-y}$ to apply Tonelli theorem I did the following

$$|f(x,y)|\leq 2x\sqrt{y}$$
But 
$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty} 2x\sqrt{y}dxdy$ is not finite. What function $g$ should I use to bound $f(x,y)$ such that $\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}<\infty$?

Comment: Simple: do not throw away the exponential part.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Do you mean $|f(x,y)|\leq 2x\sqrt{y}e^{-x^2\sqrt{y}-y}$. Do you think that it is a good idea to bound a function by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask about a bound. I think in this case, *when you want to calculate the integral*, you should not try to find a bound. Instead, argue as follows:

Call your integrand $f$. We note that $f$ is measurable since it is continuous. By the Tonelli theorem, to guarantee that $f$ is integrable over $[0,+\infty)^2$, it suffices to check that one of
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}\Bigl(\int_0^{+\infty}|f(x,y)|\,dx\Bigr)\,dy
\quad
\text{and}
\quad
\int_0^{+\infty}\Bigl(\int_0^{+\infty}|f(x,y)|\,dy\Bigr)\,dx\tag{$*$}
$$
exists. In your case the first one is in fact easily calculated (note that $f\geq 0$), as noticed in the answer by @felix-marin. Hence $f$ is integrable.

Next, by the Fubini theorem, since $f$ is integrable, the integrals in $(*)$ above are equal, and the value of the integral you want to calculate is $1$, as @felix-marin notice.

Finally, I cannot resist to suggest the book [Introduction to integration](http://www.alibris.com/booksearch?keyword=Hilary+Priestley+Introduction+to+integration&mtype=B&hs.x=0&hs.y=0) by Hilary Priestley. I wish I would have had it by my side when I first learned the theory of integration.